# PyPlot in Julia giving "no module named site" error

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I have started playing with Julia today. I was following [Steven's](https://github.com/stevengj/julia-mit/) MIT turorials to get started. However, when I reached the Plotting section I tried importing PyPlot with:

```
using PyPlot
```

however it gave me the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named site

WARNING: backtraces on your platform are often misleading or partially incorrect

could not load module python: The specified module could not be found.

at C:\Users\Dipto\.julia\PyPlot\src\PyPlot.jl:32
at In[1]:1
in pyinitialize at C:\Users\Dipto\.julia\PyCall\src\PyCall.jl:406
```

I use Canopy as my Python installation, so all modules required by pyplot should already be available on the machine.

N.B. As indicated in the tutorial I did use Pkg.add("PyPlot") in Julia to install pyplot in Julia as well.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like problem is that PyCall (the bridge between Julia and Python) does not work with Canopy. See: https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl/issues/42.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem recently after doing a package update, Pkg.update(). It gave me some errors with Nettle and whatnot during the update.

**The solution** was to delete the .julia directory and reinstall all the needed packages.

The only caveat I feel I have to give is that previous to this recent "reinstall" I used http instead of git for downloading Julia packages. I don't expect this to be an issue though.

Setup

- Windows 7 Pro 64-bit
- Julia 0.2.0 (2013-11-16 23:44 UTC)
- Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6)
- PyPlot 1.1.0

  - Anaconda (unknown version, installed October 28, 2013)